# Python not running my program without any error

Tags: python

I need to create a program that will convert Base 10 numbers in Base 2.

Next is the code, it can not run as expected even if it has no error:

```
E = input('Please enter a number') 
Eint= int(E)
for N in range(100,0):
    while 2**N > Eint:
         N = N-1 
         print(0)  
    if B**N <= Eint:
        Eint = Eint - 2**N 
        print(1)   
    Print('finished')
```

When I'm running it it will ask me the number but that's all, thank you for your help guys.

[image]

Comment: `range(100,0)` produces an empty range see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) the `0` is the `stop` arg, what range are you intending to create

Comment: sorry i didn't saw your answer. i would like it to go from a N number to 0,

Comment: Then you want `range(100,-1,-1)`

Comment: Okay thanks,i will try

Comment: now it's printing a lot of 0 except for the last term and it's printing "finished at the end"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick inspection, `range(100,0)`, `B`, and `Print()` are three culprits here!  If you want to pass through numbers from 0 to 99, then `range(100)` is what you need.  Now, what is B?  Print should be written in lower case: `print`.

After we fix these syntax errors, let us try to revisit the program and understand what it is supposed to do.  Have fun :-)

EDIT to fix the code in the question:

```
E = input('Please enter a number: ') 
Eint = int(E)
for N in range(8,-1,-1):
    if 2**N > Eint:
        print(0, end='')
    else:
        Eint = Eint - 2**N 
        print(1, end='')

print()
print('finished')
```

Please note that Python is a language that uses indentations to denote code blocks.  This code will convert a decimal to binary.  Now, note that the range start of 8 gives you a hint about the upper bound of the number that the code can translate.  Therefore, an if condition must be added after the second statement to ensure we are not attempting to convert a number that is too large.  Enjoy!

Comment: Okay.  I decided to debug the program for you.  Please see the edited response above :-)

Comment: Thank you i will try it

Comment: It worked ! thank you very much ah ah,now i will waste your time a little bit if you're okay. could you explain why did you wrote (end=' ') and why is there two print at the end ^^

Comment: You are welcome!  The `end=''` keeps the printed text on the same line.  The extra `print()` statement is to print the word "finished" on a new line.  Try to remove these lines to see what you get.  Programming is fun.  :-)

Comment: thank you for your eplanations. I really love programmation that's why in my Highschool i choosen I.S.N (that is computer science in french) and later i would like to work as an computer engineer :)

Answer (score 0):

If it helps check my solution too. Because I guess you don't want to see the result on separate lines, so I create a list for you to see the result in one line.

```
E = int(input('Please enter a number\n'))
Eint = E
base_two=[]
while E > 0:
    a = int(float(E%2))
    base_two.append(a)
    E = (E-a)/2
base_two.append(0)
string = ""
for j in base_two[::-1]:
    string = string+str(j)
print("Binary for", Eint, "is", string)
print('finished')
```

I was late a little bit :)